# What does the "set" instruction do in AVR assembly?

Tags: assembly, avr, instructions

I am trying to understand the following assembly code, but have been unsuccessful with the "set" instruction in the following code.

```
2:  dec CTR
    brne 3f
    set
```

Googling **Assembly Set Command** hasn't found it either, or any of the instruction list documentation.

Comment: Is this AVR assembly? If it is then it **SE**ts the **T** flag. http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/devicedoc/atmel-0856-avr-instruction-set-manual.pdf Page 165

Comment: That's it! Thanks for finding it for me!

Comment: you need to google for "AVR instruction list" instead of such a common search string

Answer (score 1):

It is the **SE**t **T**-flag operation in AVR Assembly.